# How to get value of the property of the child classes from the parent?

Tags: c#

I have a base class named `Template`. And i have many children classes like `TemplateChild1`, `TemplateChild2` etc that inherited `Template` class. All child classes basically have the same structure and looks like this:

```
public class TemplateChild1 : Template
{
    public const string Name = "Child class 1";
    //many other properties
}

public class TemplateChild2 : Template
{
    public const string Name = "Child class 2";
    //many other properties
}

//and many more other child classes with similar structure
```

In my task i have to show all this child classes of the `Template` class in the `ComboBox` on the form. So for this i used this code:

```
var templateTypes = Assembly
                    .GetAssembly(typeof(Template))
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Template))).ToList();
```

Then i put this list at the `ComboBox` and it works fine. But in `ComboBox` i see only the developing name of the class, but not the value of the `Name` property. For example, instead of "Child class 1"/"Child class 2"/etc. , i see TemplateChild1/TemplateChild2/etc. How can i fix that problem?

Comment: These classes as you have posted them don't inherit from anything. name should be a property of `Template`, not the derived classes.

Comment: Yes, now i edited it and it's inheriting parent class. I also thought about that. But what if i need a Name as a constant property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your notions of inheritance a little upside-down. If both Child1 and Child2 have a "Name" property, you make the Name a property of the parent (all children then have a Name), and then you can treat all children as if they were an instance of their parent, and get the Name

```
List<Parent> x = new List<Parent>();

x.Add(new TemplateChild1());
x.Add(new TemplateChild2());

myCombo.DataSource = x;
myCombo.DisplayMember = "Name"; //tell databinding to use the Name property for the displaytext
```

For a class setup of:

```
public class Parent{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public class TemplateChild1: Parent
{
    public TemplateChild1(){
        Name = "Child one";
    }
}

public class TemplateChild2: Parent
{
    public TemplateChild2(){
        Name = "Child two";
    }
}
```

Now all the items in the combo, be they a Child1 or a Child2, show the text assigned to their Name property. The `set` is protected; it can only be accessed by children of the Parent. The constructors for the children set the value of Name, and it cannot then be set to something else (well.. except by another child. If you want to prevent that, make the children not inheritable), hence it's now constant

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the other answer, the question originally made use of constants. You can't do this with a base class, but you can make your properties `readonly` this will at least prevent them from being written to outside of the base class constructor.

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Template(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class TemplateChild1: Template
{
    public TemplateChild1()
        : base("Child one")
    { }
}
```